# Printing the last int value stored in an array

Tags: java

I have initialized an array int numArray to store 10 values . Now I want my program to print the last value stored in this array. I have used this code but really didn't work.

```
System.out.printIn(numArray[numArray.length-1])
```

or I shall go with

```
int result = numArray.size;
System.out.printIn(result);
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You should have gotten a compilation error due to your spelling mistake on `System.out.println` (using I intead of l).

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html. And next time, rather than telling us "it doesn't work", **read** the error message, google for this message to understand what it means if it isn't clear, and then ask us what it means if you really can't understand. Error messages are intended to be read, and are much more precise than "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 4):

You should do:

```
System.out.println(numArray[numArray.length-1])
//              ^ lower case L, not upper case i
```

The second option will give you the size of the array, not the value of the last element.

Answer (score 3):

It probably doesn't work because `printIn` is not `println`.

Other than that, assuming the size of the array is ten and you've placed ten elements in it, what you have as your first option will work fine. It will give you the last element.

Your second option will only give you the size, not the last element.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(numArray[numArray.length-1])` will print the last value. 
`System.out.println(numArray.size)` prints the size of the array... not the value.